# Unexpected token babel. React.js without webpack

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

```
<script src="~/js/react-js/react.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/react-js/react-dom.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/react-js/babel.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="~/js/react-js/components/app.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


 <script type="text/babel">
           setTimeout(() => ReactDOM.render(
             <App dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html : "<div>HTML</div>" } />, 
             document.getElementById("manual-content")), 0)
 </script> 





Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (2:104)
      1 | 
    > 2 |         setTimeout(() => ReactDOM.render(<App dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html : "<div>HTML</div>" } }/>, document.getElementById("manual-content")), 0)
        |                                                                                                         ^
      3 |
```

what's wrong. why babel gives an error. I can not understand.

I want to transfer the markup but the babel doesn't work for some reason. I do not use webpack collectors

I am using file connection via script tags